# Making a POST request in Angular 2 with JSON body

Tags: json, rest, http, angular

I am making some POST requests using POSTMAN as follows:

[image]

This is using POSTMAN and it works just fine. Following is also from POSTMAN

```
POST /supervisor/stop/process HTTP/1.1
Host: bento
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 66b05631-8b4e-473a-9d3f-deaa544ecac6

{
"ip" : "192.168.1.115",
"port" : "9001",
"process" : "public_video_convert:video_convert_01"
}
```

I tried the same thing using Angular 2 as follows:

```
let url = "http://bento/supervisor/stop/process";
        let data = {
            "ip": "192.168.1.115",
            "port": "9001",
            "process": "public_video_convert:video_convert_01"
        }
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let head = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        this.http.post(url, body, {headers : head})
            .map(res =>  res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => {console.log(data);},
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('Fetching complete for Server Metrics')
            );
```

When I run this, I get a `405 Method Not Allowed`

The details of the request and and the response from dev tools is as follows:

[image]

I am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: I think the `PreFlight` request is failing. Do you control the server? `HTTP OPTIONS` reqyests might not have been enabled there.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, OPTIONS requests were not served. I made use of the following tool :

https://github.com/jdesrosiers/silex-cors-provider

It now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

You are getting the 405  from the server because it does not know how to handle "OPTIONS" requests (hence the "Method Not Allowed" response).

### Now the details

This is a "preflight" request that gets sent from the browser if you are sending a "Not Simple" request to a different domain (in this case, your web page is hosted by evil.com and tries to send an xhr to bento). For your example, what makes your request "Not Simple" is the header "Content-type":"application/json".

This happens when your web app makes a cross-origin Request. In general, there are two scenarios:

You are either sending a "simple" request, in which case the browser sends it directly ( With the Origin Header), or, you are sending a "not Simple" request, in which case the browser sends out the preflight request (OPTIONS) to the server first to confirm that the origin is listed in the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", and then sends out the actual request.

More details on Cross-Origin Resource Sharing here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

Currently only text is supported by Angulars `Http`. There are plans to support other body types https://github.com/angular/http/issues/75

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to import the `Headers` class:

```
import {Http,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
```

In this case, your custom headers won't be added to the request. I can't see the Content-Type header into the details of the request and and the response from dev tools you provided. This header should be sent within the request based the code you provided (except the imports).

The server doesn't seem to support the POST method without a JSON content type. That's why you receive a 405 error...